# pthread_create ENOMEM around 32000 threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

The process running get stuck around 32 000 (± 5%)

~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max 
127862

~# ulimit -s
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 2048

free memory available : 3,5 Go

Further more when I try basic command while the process is stuck like "top", I get the bash message : can't fork, not enough memory.
Even if there is still 3,5 Go of free memory.

What could be limit the thread creation at 32 000 ?

Comment: The `threads-max` value is a system-wide limit.  There may be a per-process limit also.  But why would you ever want/need that many threads?  Is it a synthetic scheduler test?

Comment: On FreeBSD, yes but not on debian, with is the ditribution used...
For stress testing the Core i7

Comment: I think you're stress testing the scheduler, rather than the cpu.

Comment: what makes you think you're stress testing the CPU by creating thousands of threads? You're not, you're stress testing the OS, and the thread scheduler. Your CPU only has a fixed number of cores, so it  only run a fixed number of threads at a time. If you want to stress test the CPU, you need to minimize all other factors that could stall the CPU -- such as page faults and memory latency, both of which you're going to have lots of if you want the OS to constantly switch between running 32000 threads each with their own stack at their own place in RAM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Threads are identified with Thread IDs (TIDs), which are just PIDs in Linux, and...

```
~% sysctl kernel.pid_max
kernel.pid_max = 32768
```

PIDs in Linux are 16-bit, and 32768 is already the maximum value allowed. With that many threads, you have just completely filled the operating system process table. I don't think you will be able to create more threads than that.

Anyways, there is something **really** wrong with your design if you need that many threads. There is really no justification to have that many.

Comment: According to `man gettid` on my system thread IDs are not PIDs. Only for a single-threaded application is the thread id the same as the PID.

Comment: Also, it appears that `pid_t` on my system ultimately resolves to `int`.

Comment: It seems that did the trick ! Thank you Juliano !

Yes I know the design is broken, we just needed to do some benchmark on a Core i7 to see how fast it switch from thread to thread

Comment: @user374215: What gettid(2) mentions is about the semantics of a PID and a TID. Yes, they are different. But in the internal process table, both processes and threads share the same namespace, and that namespace is limited by kernel.pid_max.

Comment: In fact the server does not get me the usual "Fork" issue.... but the number of threads is still stuck at ± 32000
It is very annoying !

Answer (score 6):

almost 10 years later: kernel 5.6. There is a limit in kernel/fork.c: see max_threads/2.

But the main culprit are mmaps. See `strace` output:

> mprotect(0x7fbff49ba000, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot > allocate memory)

Increase `/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count` for more threads.